# Ansible. Как повторно выполнить imported/included task при ее неудачном выполнении

Tags: ansible

Есть список базовых task. В основном плейбуке мне необходимо ее использовать с дополнительным условием - `until: result is not failed`

Текущий код не работает, после первого же провала плейбук завершает выполнение

```
- tesks ... 
  - name: abc
    include_tasls: start_process.yml
    register: result
    until: result is not failed
    retries: 3
    delay: 10
```

Замена include_tasls на import_task/playbook не помогла.

Есть ли способ не меняя базовой задачи добавить условие повтора при неудаче?

Comment: В смысле? У тебя не работает связка `until\retries\delay`?

Comment: @donRumata она не работает если я ее использую в таске `abc` где есть `include_tasks`. Если `until\retries\delay` находится непосредственно в `start_process.yml`, все работает правильно. Я подозреваю что в случае из вопроса `retires` нацеленны непосредственно на успех включения `include_tasks`, а не на действия которые в этой таске происходят

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61925383 тут говорят, что надо пихать в саму таску.